# How do I find the where a particle goes through a plane with a normal unit vector?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors

[image]

Need help finding this. Is Q just the partial derivative of the function?

So I just do this:

$$\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:x}\left(2z^2-x^4-y^4\right)=-4x^3$$
$$\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:y}\left(2z^2-x^4-y^4\right)=-4y^3$$
$$\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:z}\left(2z^2-x^4-y^4\right)=4z$$

Is this right? I don't know what to do from here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of a straight line that through a point $\mathbf p$ and has the direction $\mathbf n$ is
$$
\mathbf r = \mathbf p + \lambda \mathbf n \ ;\qquad \lambda  \in \mathbb R
$$
We have
$$
\mathbf n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{74}}(8,1,-3)^T ,\quad \mathbf p = (2,1,3)^T
$$
the first equation in coordinates form becomes
$$
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}p_1 + \lambda n_1\\p_2 + \lambda n_2\\p_3 + \lambda n_3\end{pmatrix}
$$
Intersecting the $xy$-plane means $z =0$. The equation for $z$ you have $\lambda > 0$ that solves
$$
0 = p_3 + \lambda n_3 \implies \lambda = - \frac{p_3}{n_3} = -\frac{3}{-3/\sqrt{74}} = \sqrt{74}
$$
Substitiute this $\lambda$ in the equation for $x$ and $y$ to get the coordinates of $\mathbf Q$
$$
x = p_1 + \lambda n_1 = 2 + \sqrt{74}\frac{8}{\sqrt{74}} = 10\\
y = p_2 + \lambda n_2 = 1 + \sqrt{74}\frac{1}{\sqrt{74}} = 2 
$$

Comment: $$y=1+\left(-\frac{3}{\sqrt{74}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{74}}\right)$$

Comment: $$x=2+\left(-\frac{3}{\sqrt{74}}\right)\left(\frac{8}{\sqrt{74}}\right)$$

Comment: it's telling me it's wrong my answer is wrong. what am I doing wrong?